# Extract array data from full HTML page returned from a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have some JavaScript code:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
        var response = req.responseText;
        console.log(response);
    }
};

req.open('GET', 'https://circumvent-cors.herokuapp.com/https://weather.rap.ucar.edu/radar/displayRad.php?icao=KLWX&prod=BREF&bkgr=gray&endTime=-1&duration=2');
req.send(null);
```

which returns a HTML page like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>NEXRAD Level-II radar image(s) [KLWX BREF]</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
    <meta name="author" content="Gregory Thompson" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="(c) Copyright UCAR-University Corporation for Atmospheric Research All Rights Reserved" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/reset.css" />
    <!-- Include the SciAnimator CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/scianimator.css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <h2>NEXRAD Level-II radar image(s) [KLWX BREF]</h2>
  <p align="left">
    Generated Mon, 11 Apr 2022  21:04:51 UTC by <a href="https://weather.ral.ucar.edu/radar">https://weather.ral.ucar.edu/radar</a>
    <br clear="all" />
  Please wait for <U>18</U> images to load.<br clear="all" />
  </p>
  <p align="left">
  <hr size="4" width="75%" />
<!-- Container elements in which SciAnimators will go -->
<div id="scianimator"></div>
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include SciAnimator script. Choose your compression level. -->
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.scianimator.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/assets/js/jquery.scianimator.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
$('#scianimator').scianimator({
  'controlPosition': 0,
  'images': ["../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_190900_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_191500_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_192200_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_192900_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_193600_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_194200_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_194900_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_195600_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_200300_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_201000_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_201600_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_202300_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_203000_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_204000_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_204500_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_204900_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_205400_BREF_gray.png","../data/radar/20220411/KLWX/BREF/KLWX_20220411_205800_BREF_gray.png"],
  'theme': 'dark',
  'delay': 250,
  'delayStep': 25,
  'dwellMultiplier': 4,
  'utf8': false
}).scianimator('play');
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: **how would I be able to parse that response, to get the *images* array from the response shown?** The `images` array is under `$('#scianimator').scianimator({`. I would like to take that array and be able to use it with `scianimator`, but I can do that myself.

I would just like to know how I can extract that array from the response to be used later.

Comment: I will not post this as a comment as an answer, but if you are looking for transparent radar imagery, you might want to check out https://mrms.ncep.oaa.gov/data/RIDGEII/L2/KLWX/ (RIDGE II) - this imagery is GeoTIF (transparent) and contains super-res reflectivity and velocity (not dealiased, sadly). If you need the imagery over map data, you can check out https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/lite/KLWX_0.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to extract the data

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
        var response = req.responseText;
        var matches = response.match(/'images':\s*(\[.+?\])/);
        if (matches){
            img_arr = JSON.parse(matches[1]);
            console.log(img_arr);
        }
        else{
            console.log(':(');
        }
    }
};

req.open('GET', getURL());
req.send(null);

function getURL(){
    return 'https://circumvent-cors.herokuapp.com/https://weather.rap.ucar.edu/radar/displayRad.php?icao=KLWX&prod=BREF&bkgr=gray&endTime=-1&duration=2';
    //return `data:text/html,%3C!doctype%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%20lang%3D%22en%22%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ENEXRAD%20Level-II%20radar%20image(s)%20%5BKLWX%20BREF%5D%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset%3D%22utf-8%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20http-equiv%3D%22Content-Type%22%20content%3D%22text%2Fhtml%3B%20charset%3DISO-8859-1%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20http-equiv%3D%22Content-Language%22%20content%3D%22en-us%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20name%3D%22author%22%20content%3D%22Gregory%20Thompson%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20name%3D%22copyright%22%20content%3D%22(c)%20Copyright%20UCAR-University%20Corporation%20for%20Atmospheric%20Research%20All%20Rights%20Reserved%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel%3D%22stylesheet%22%20href%3D%22%2Fassets%2Fcss%2Freset.css%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20Include%20the%20SciAnimator%20CSS%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel%3D%22stylesheet%22%20href%3D%22%2Fassets%2Fcss%2Fscianimator.css%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody%20bgcolor%3D%22%23FFFFFF%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Ch2%3ENEXRAD%20Level-II%20radar%20image(s)%20%5BKLWX%20BREF%5D%3C%2Fh2%3E%0A%20%20%3Cp%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20Generated%20Mon%2C%2011%20Apr%202022%20%2021%3A04%3A51%20UTC%20by%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fweather.ral.ucar.edu%2Fradar%22%3Ehttps%3A%2F%2Fweather.ral.ucar.edu%2Fradar%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20clear%3D%22all%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20Please%20wait%20for%20%3CU%3E18%3C%2FU%3E%20images%20to%20load.%3Cbr%20clear%3D%22all%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%3Cp%20align%3D%22left%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Chr%20size%3D%224%22%20width%3D%2275%25%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C!--%20Container%20elements%20in%20which%20SciAnimators%20will%20go%20--%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22scianimator%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C!--%20Include%20jQuery%20--%3E%0A%3Cscript%20src%3D%22%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.4.4.min.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%3C!--%20Include%20SciAnimator%20script.%20Choose%20your%20compression%20level.%20--%3E%0A%3Cscript%20src%3D%22%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fjquery.scianimator.min.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%3C!--%20%3Cscript%20src%3D%22%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fjquery.scianimator.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%20--%3E%0A%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%3E%0A%2F*%3C!%5BCDATA%5B*%2F%0AjQuery(function(%24)%20%7B%0A%24('%23scianimator').scianimator(%7B%0A%20%20'controlPosition'%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20'images'%3A%20%5B%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_190900_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_191500_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_192200_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_192900_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_193600_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_194200_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_194900_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_195600_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_200300_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_201000_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_201600_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_202300_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_203000_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_204000_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_204500_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_204900_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_205400_BREF_gray.png%22%2C%22..%2Fdata%2Fradar%2F20220411%2FKLWX%2FBREF%2FKLWX_20220411_205800_BREF_gray.png%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20'theme'%3A%20'dark'%2C%0A%20%20'delay'%3A%20250%2C%0A%20%20'delayStep'%3A%2025%2C%0A%20%20'dwellMultiplier'%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20'utf8'%3A%20false%0A%7D).scianimator('play')%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A%2F*%5D%5D%3E*%2F%0A%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E`;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and it works great for parsing the HTML string I want. However, when I try to pass the string into your code, it doesn't work. This is what I have:

`var dataURI = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(myHTMLdataVariable);`

Where I parse it into a data:text/html string, and then I pass it into the getURL function:


`function getURL(){
     return dataURI;
}`

Is there a way to pass a variable HTML string?

Comment: I used the data uri as an example as the proxy you supplied didn't work for me. Get the html string the way you normally get it.

Comment: This is a new proxy that shouldn't rate limit you, maybe try this? `https://circumvent-cors.herokuapp.com/https://weather.rap.ucar.edu/radar/displayRad.php?icao=KLWX&prod=BREF&bkgr=gray&endTime=-1&duration=2`

Comment: Yes, just use this url instead of the data uri.

Comment: It worked - I'm an idiot and was using a previous `$().get` response instead of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation correctly,
the data isn't contained in the html sent by the browser;
instead the html contains some js that fetches the data when a broswer renders it.

I would say you have 2 options:

1. the heavy one (but robust) -
   use a library like `Puppeteer` to automate a browser to visit this url and to perform a `querySelector` there.
2. the light one (that works more often that you'd think) -
   visit your link, open chrome's Network panel, and search what request the page has sent to get the actual data. it's probably a simple POST request